# How may I vary the opacity of mesh points by reference to their original coordinates

Tags: plotting

I'm using `ParametricPlot3D` to show only the mesh points, but would like to vary their opacity by reference to a function of their original position.

```
ParametricPlot3D[
  Table[{X + Y, Y + Z, X + Z}, {X, -3, 3}, {Y, -3, 3}], {Z, -3, 3}, 
  Axes -> False, Mesh -> All, PlotStyle -> None, 
  MeshStyle -> Directive[PointSize[Small], Opacity[Abs[X]/7]], 
  PlotPoints -> 7, MaxRecursion -> 0]
```

Clearly not working. Help gratefully received, I am very new to *Mathematica*.

Comment: The variable `X` only exists in `Table`. It is not known to `ParametricPlot3D`.

Comment: Why don't use directly `Graphics` and `Point` to draw the collection of points?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know to make what you want work with `ParametricPlot3D`, but it's not too hard with plain, old `Graphics3D`. Here is one way it can be done.

I use `Table` and `Cases` and `Transpose` to make a list containing two lists, the 1st being the source points and the 2nd being the image points.

```
data = 
  Transpose @
    Cases[
      Table[
        {{x, y, z}, {x + y, y + z, x + z}}, 
        {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, {z, -3, 3}],
      _, {-3}];
```

Then I render the points with varying opacity, taking the x-coordinate of each source point from the 1st of two lists in `data` and using it in opacity computation. The positions of the plotted image points are taken from the 2nd list.

```
Graphics3D[
  MapThread[
    {Opacity[.1 + .3 Abs[#1[[1]]]], 
       Glow[RGBColor[1/10, 2/3, 1]], 
         Sphere[#2, Scaled[.005]]} &, 
     data],
  BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1},
  Lighting -> None]
```

[image: points]

Notes:

- I used `Sphere` rather than `Point` to render the points because I think spheres look better in 3D graphics.
- I turned lighting off and used `Glow` to color the spheres with a shade of blue that I favor.
- I scaled the opacity to remain in the range 0 to 1. In the scaling expression `#1[[1]]]` designates the x-coordinate of the source points.

Comment: thanks, this worked a treat for me, and I learned a lot more applying it to my more complicated real life example !

Answer (score 0):

For the specific case, you can also solve for `X` and post-process the `ParametricPlot3D` output to change the opacities:

```
pp = ParametricPlot3D[
   Table[{X + Y, Y + Z, X + Z}, {X, -3, 3}, {Y, -3, 3}], {Z, -3, 3}, 
   Axes -> False, Mesh -> All, PlotStyle -> None, 
   MeshStyle -> Directive[PointSize[Large], Blue], PlotPoints -> 7, 
   MaxRecursion -> 0];
X /. Solve[{X + Y, Y + Z, X + Z} == {u, v, w}, {X, Y, Z}]
```

> { (u - v + w)/2}

```
Row[{pp, Normal[pp] /. 
   Point[x_] :> {Opacity[Abs[(1/2) (x[[1]] - x[[2]] + x[[3]])]/7], Point[x]}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can also use

```
foo = Abs[(# - #2 + #3)/2]/7 &;
Normal[pp] /. Point[x_] :> {Opacity[foo @@ x], Point[x]}
```

to get the same result.